# Why isn't this code getting the name of the file?

Tags: bash

In a folder containing many files like this:

```
filtered_bcbc8273.bam
filtered_a8626340.bam
filtered_fae86ca5.bam
```

I want to use samtools (it adds .bam in the end) to sort them and save the sorted file as:

```
sorted_bcbc8273.bam
sorted_a8626340.bam
sorted_fae86ca5.bam
```

but my output is:

```
sorted_.bam
```

what's wrong here?

```
cd /work/folder/
for l in *; do
name=$(echo "$l" | cut -d "_" -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1)
samtools sort -n /work/folder/filtered_$name\.bam /work/folder/sorted/sorted_$name\
cd ..
done
```

Comment: If you put a `cd ..` inside your loop, then you're sure to be in the wrong  directory for every item other than the first.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: That's true, but nothing inside the loop actually depends on being in the right directory.

Comment: @ruakh, I couldn't say whether that's true or not without knowing `samtools` and its semantics. (Can processing a file include other files? What's the searth path look like? Etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make its behavior a bit more reliable, I'd suggest rewriting this like so:

```
cd /work/folder
for f in filtered_*.bam; do
  [[ -e $f ]] || continue  # skip any file that doesn't exist (ie. glob failed)
  id=${f#filtered_}                  # strip prefix from filename
  id=${id%.bam}                      # strip suffix from filename
  samtools sort -n "$f" "sorted_$id" # run tool
done
```

Advantages:

- Using the more specific glob expression (`filtered_*.bam`) ensures that names meet our expectations, and thus that we aren't failing due to iterating over files that don't match our expected pattern.
- Using parameter expansions for trimming known prefixes and suffixes prevents the `cut` operations from removing anything other than those known prefixes or suffixes, thus behaving more reliably.
- Using the shell's built-in string manipulation is faster than forking a subshell to launch an external tool (when doing so within an inner loop; an external tool can be more efficient when structured to be run only once for an entire stream of inputs).

Finally, having the `cd ..` within the loop ensured that until your working directory reached the root, each loop iteration would be run in a different directory.

See [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for more detail on bash's string-manipulation primitives in general, or [the bash-hackers parameter expansion page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for a focused explanation of the primitives used and others akin to them.